# Rename files on Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, rename

I would like to rename my file C6Y5DACXX-2-ID01_1_sequence.fastq to C6Y5DACXX-2-ID01_sequence_1.fastq

I am running a program that requires the input of the fastq files to be _1.fastq and _2.fastq

Kindly assist.

Comment: Hello all I would like to make a batch rename.

Answer (score 2):

You use command `mv filename new_filename`

Here is my terminal for your filenames:

```
marko@DevLaptop:~/test$ touch C6Y5DACXX-2-ID01_1_sequence.fastq
marko@DevLaptop:~/test$ ls
C6Y5DACXX-2-ID01_1_sequence.fastq
marko@DevLaptop:~/test$ mv C6Y5DACXX-2-ID01_1_sequence.fastq C6Y5DACXX-2-ID01_sequence_1.fastq
marko@DevLaptop:~/test$ ls
C6Y5DACXX-2-ID01_sequence_1.fastq
```

And to replace all `1_sequence` to `sequence_1` you can use

`rename 's/1_sequence/sequence_1/' *.fastq`

Comment: Hello Marko could you kindly use my input characters for your answer. I posses very basic skills on use of the command line and its language.

Comment: Hello all I would like to make a batch rename.

Comment: ah you would like to rename all files

Comment: Now one more question, I should write a script that renames all `1_sequence` to `sequence_1`

Comment: Yes exactly that is it

Comment: Hello Marko do you an answer??

Comment: @SamieZizouK I hopefully answered now :)

Answer (score 1):

you can rename like this

```
mv "name.txt" "new_name.txt"
```

you can change the file format like this

```
mv "name.txt" "new_name.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rename the file using **mv** command.Though **mv** command is used to move the contents of a folder to other destination,but when the arguments are files then it starts to behave differently i.e it renames.

```
mv stack.css stackOverflow.css
```

The name **stack.css** will be changed to **stackOverflow.css**